# Python multiprocessing min span tree - entire program loops

Tags: python, loops, multiprocessing

I am trying to use multiprocessing in Python to speed up a **minimum spanning tree algorithm** for a large amount of data. The tree is using **Prim's method**. In short I have a program that creates a weighted matrix for each category and then enters the routine to make the min span tree, inside this routine I have this code

```
 if __name__=='__main__':
        m=Manager()
        q=Queue()
        #wt=partial(_lightest_edge_weight, graph=graph, visited=visited)
        p=Pool()
        #go to each visited edge
        for each in visited:
            q.put(each)
        q.put('DONE')
        #set up multiprocessing for edges in queue
        p.apply_async(target=_lightest_edge_weight, args=(graph,visited,q,))
```

However, whenever I do this (and I have tried using Process plus start and join as well) the new processes that open up restart the entire program instead of just running the items in the queue against `_lightest_edge_weight`. Any ideas while the whole program loops instead of just the target subroutine? Thanks.

Comment: If you have *any* code that runs outside of `if __name__ == '__main__'`, that's your problem. If not, I need more code than what you've given.

Comment: I am agreeing with @Veedrac. Make yourself a contrived example to prove this. Side comment: I don't recall apply_async having a target kwd. Are you sure this is valid code?

Comment: Not knowing how large your "large amount of data" is, also consider to optimize the algorithm. It might be worth to try a different algorithm, too. For instance I found an implementation of Kruskal's algorithm to be ~15x faster than the implementation of Prim's algorithm [here](http://peekaboo-vision.blogspot.de/2012/02/simplistic-minimum-spanning-tree-in.html)